# How to take numerical input form user when user says something like - "Double nine"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to take phone number from user and am able to successfully do so if the user uses no short form. But if the user says something like "Double nine seven three four three eight two double six" for the phone number 9973438266, as is the case with a lot of users, alexa can't convert it to a number. Is there any way I can take these utterances from user for the phone number?

As I am using ENGLISH-IN, I am not able to use the default phone number slot provided by amazon. Instead, I am using two AMAZON.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER slots followed by two AMAZON.NUMBER slots to take the 10 digit number.
I parse it in sequence in a Lambda function using python.

If the user says "Double (some number)", Alexa behaves unreliably. Sometimes it sends a question mark (?) in one of these four slots, and sometimes some other request is called. I couldn't find an answer on the web, including aws and alexa documentation. I need a reliable solution to take these utterances. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think at the moment there's no way to handle input like a "double nine".

Probably the best way to go is to tell the user that each digit has to be said seperately or maybe even make a response after each digit and ask for the next one.

But I think the general idea is good, maybe you could request this feature [here](https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote).